# After changing extension html to php, page redirected

Tags: php, html, html5boilerplate

I have changed my file extension, HTML to PHP. When I browse in localhost, it is redirected to main server. I am using github and files are developed using HTML5boilerplate with twitter bootstrap. I have committed in github several with the extension HTML. 
i.e.
my previous url: `[localhost]/sovolve.com/new/index.html`
current url: `[localhost]/sovolve.com/new/index.php`

when I browse in localhost with current URL it is redirected to `http://sovolve.com/new/index.html`

Please let me know someone if codes need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Is both index.php and index.html pages are present in same document root ??

If present apache gives priority to the index.html rather than index.php.

Please delete that index.html. It will fix your issue.

Are you using .htaccess. Give in details.

If yes use below code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it is simple html page. I do not use .htaccess. Moreover, there is no both file because I changed the extension of html file to php. So, there is only index.php

Comment: thanks @Sanjog, actually my problem is not to redirect something. My issue is simple, I run an html file after changing it's extension, it's redirect somewhere (server). This is not in .htaccess issue. Perhaps in GITHUB